# supremum and infinum of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the $\sup (\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1})=1$ where $0<x<1$.

How do I get the sup of this function? Please show me step by step or give me some advice.

Comment: I believe $x<0$?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the function defined? 
Because if it is defined in all R, it has no supreme. Note that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}=\infty$.

Comment: The function is defined for 0<x<1

Comment: So in that case the supreme is not 1. Note that the function is increasing in (0,1) (compute the first derivative) therefore $$\sup (xe^x/(e^x-1))=e/(e-1)$$ for 0<x<1